# Ignite - External Storage - reload didn't work

Tags: storage, external, ignite

In my application I have cache that fills up from External Storage (Postgres database). All configurations are similar to examples in developer guide.

I load data using this code:

```
ignite.cache("ProductCache").loadCache(null);
```

and it works okey.

But if I change data in External Storage (insert/update/delete) and then again load data with the same code thats changes do not appear in cache.

But if I restart application and load data it's all rigth - I see changes.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `ignite.cache.clear()` first, then `loadCache(null)`. Otherwise, Ignite will not overwrite entries which are already present (by key).